# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 : Cannot connect to (local))

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I installed sql server 2008 on my computer. Now when I am trying to connect so that i can create database tables etc, I am getting following error :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
```

Well I am trying to connect using following setting (see screen shot below)

[image: a busy cat]

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks..
Anjum

Comment: Are you sure you installed Sql Server not just the Sql Server Management studio ?

Comment: Goto Administrative Tools->Services and find MSSQLSERVER service. make sure the service is started or not.

Comment: I have checked in 'services' in my windows, SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) is running

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Comment: @NagarajS Por 1433 will be very helpfull when a ocnnection with named pipes is attempted. Try reading the error message. Local avoids the TCP/IP overhead and uses named pipes (shared memory on the same machine).

Comment: @Anjum then you should try like this `YourPCName\SQLEXPRESS` as a server name instead of `(Local)`.

Comment: @M.Ali, I think you are correct ? How can i check that ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you windows user doesn't has permission to connect? Try to use SQL server auth if it  is possible.

Comment: No. Authentication/Authorization errors give a sensible error message, explaining that the user is not allowed.